# $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ where $\operatorname{Col}A=\operatorname{Nul}A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Can someone provide an example of a $2 \times2$ matrix $A$ where $\operatorname{Col}A = \operatorname{Nul}A$, and explain how this is the case?

In General, under what conditions on $A$,   $\operatorname{Col}A = \operatorname{Nul}A$ holds?

Thank you!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513347/can-a-matrix-have-a-null-space-that-is-equal-to-its-column-space

Comment: $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.  Calculate $\operatorname{Col}A$ and $\operatorname{Nul}A$.  For the last question, if $A$ is $n\times n$, then conditions for $\operatorname{Col}A = \operatorname{Nul}A$ is $n=2k$ and $\operatorname{Nul}A=k$.